# Convert IP address to IP range

Tags: bash

I am working a project in which I am building my own network monitor and I am stuck on a bit of a problem. I was wondering how to convert a IP address to an IP address range. So far this is what I have:

```
# figure out the raspbery pi ip address so that can figure out ip range of network
pi_ip_addr=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }')

# figure out ip address range based on pi ip address
ip_addr_trunk=$(echo $pi_ip_addr | cut -d . -f 1-3)

# append .{1..255} to provide a ip address based on current ip address of raspberry pi
ip_addr_range=$ip_addr_trunk".{1..255}"
```

So I thought this would work. However when I pass this ip_addr_range variable to another bash script that pings all IP addresses in the range it fails. The error it produces in the command line is this:

```
ping: unknown host 192.168.2.{1..255}
```

I'm guessing the problem here is when I appended the .{1..255} is somehow converting the variable to a string. Thus the loop cannot ping each IP address individually. Can anyone tell me how to successfully append the required range to the first portion of the IP address.

Comment: Shell variables are almost *all* strings. (And when they aren't they are integers or arrays not "IP addresses".) Your problem is that brace expansion doesn't happen in quotes/variables.

Comment: You shouldn't just assume 1-255. Not all networks are /24 subnets. Check the netmask! This also ignores IPv6 networks.

Comment: @EmilVikström the net mask in my case is 255.255.255.0, so the 1-255 will work. Any suggestions on what I can read to make my solution more encompassing of not all networks being /24 subnets and IPv6 networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an array, not a regular parameter.

```
ip_addr_range=( "$ip_addr_trunk".{1..255} )

for ip_addr in "${ip_addr_range[@]}"; do
    ping "$ip_addr"
done
```